# Стилистические приемы

Tags: стилистика

Каким стилистическим приемом можно было бы описать междометие "Тю-тю"?
И каким приемом в данном контексте является повторение: "Ты обращаешься за этим ко мне, КО МНЕ (в тексте заглавными буквами выделено не было)???"?

Comment: "Тю-тю" - ономатопея, наверное: подражание звуку испуганной улетающей птицы. А "ко мне" - усиление повтором, эмфаза.

Comment: Так зачем выделять?

Comment: shampar, что зачем выделять?

Answer (score 1):

Да, действительно, тю-тю - ономатопея. См.: Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва 2004
А повтор в данном случае, как отметил Виктор, эмфаза.